# Is this the right way to change the Hyperlink color in my master page as I navigate to other pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am trying to change the color of the hyperlinks in my master pages as I navigate to other pages.

Here is my code inside page_load of my master page which I thought would work.

```
 if(!IsPostBack)
    {
    if(Session["Clicked"]=="HyperLink1"){HyperLink1.Style.Add("color", "#009900")};
    if(Session["Clicked"]=="HyperLink2"){HyperLink2.Style.Add("color", "#009900")};
    if(Session["Clicked"]=="HyperLink3"){HyperLink3.Style.Add("color", "#009900")};
    if(Session["Clicked"]=="HyperLink4"){HyperLink4.Style.Add("color", "#009900")};
    if(Session["Clicked"]=="HyperLink5"){HyperLink5.Style.Add("color", "#009900")};
    }
```

And then in each page, I wrote something like this under page_load of that page.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
  {
      Session["Clicked"]="HyperLink3";
  }
```

I get an "expected ;" error when I run this. But to be frank I tried a lot to get rid of it. I know it is something very simple and I cant find it. Is this even the right way to change the hyperlink color?

Comment: You only need CSS to do this ;-)

Comment: Just trying to clarify, you want the hyperlink for the "current" page to be a different color.  Is this correct?  For instance, if you are on the About page, you want the About link to be a different color.

Comment: @CM No it has to be the same color for all the links but I am not able to do this using CSS. I am using an"asp:hyperlink" control.

Comment: CSS is the proper solution.  Several have mentioned it below.  ASP.NET will render an asp:hyperlink control to an <a href=".."></a> HTML tag, so if you tried it in a stylesheet, and it did not work, then you probably have an over-riding style in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semicolon goes for statement not for the bracket

```
 if(!IsPostBack)
{
if(Session["Clicked"]=="HyperLink1"){HyperLink1.Style.Add("color", "#009900");}
if(Session["Clicked"]=="HyperLink2"){HyperLink2.Style.Add("color", "#009900");}
if(Session["Clicked"]=="HyperLink3"){HyperLink3.Style.Add("color", "#009900");}
if(Session["Clicked"]=="HyperLink4"){HyperLink4.Style.Add("color", "#009900");}
if(Session["Clicked"]=="HyperLink5"){HyperLink5.Style.Add("color", "#009900");}
}
```

That's why your getting expected `;`

ASP Hyperlink

`<asp:HyperLink id="homelink" CssClass="linkstuff" runat="server">`

```
.linkstuff a:visited{
      color: #009900;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. But the color of the link now is #009900 even before I click on it. Looks like only the color of the text got changed. How do I make it change only after I navigate to that page?

Comment: I feel its better to do it with CSS .. Check what I've added

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this would be with a stylesheet:

```
a:visited {
     color: #009900;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a huge overkill for regular hyperlinks. Any reason you don't use CSS ":visited" selector?

In your CSS definition, add

```
a:visited
{
color: #009900;
}
```

Comment: I used the <asp:hyperlink> control to insert the hyperlink. I had tried the "a:visited" before but that didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Is it possible that the code generated from `<asp:Hyperlink>` specifies its own color, e.g. in its own CssClass? If it's the case, you need to change the `a:visited` to something like `a.myHyperLinkClass:visited` where `myHyperLinkClass` is the CssClass of the `<asp:Hyperlink>`